# Is it a sign of a bandwidth issue when network "link speed" in Speccy is mostly under 20Kbps and then every 10 seconds or so jumps to over 800 Kbps

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet-speed

The company relocated to new offices this past week and my Windows 10 PC is now back online.  When I open up Speccy and look at network "link speed" it is mostly reading between 2 and 20 Kbps but every 10 or 15 seconds or so, it jumps to over 800 Kbps.  Are those low speeds punctuated periodically by massive speed jumps a normal thing, or a sign that there's a network bandwidth problem?

[image: Network Link Speed]

Comment: Maybe you should first lay out your expectations. We don’t know whether this is upload or download. We don’t know what you were doing on the PC. We don’t know whether your PC offers services on the network. We don’t know how others use the network.

Comment: I am not doing anything other than looking at the fluctuating graph and my question is "What to conclude, if anything, from this data"? Is that kind of fluctuation normal? What is Speccy measuring?  Are brief moments of high-speed and mostly speeds below 20 Kbps typical? If that was your company would you be investigating something or satisfied that things were normal?

Comment: Then an answer is not possible. _You_ must figure out what Speccy is measuring, or just use a tool that separates incoming and outgoing traffic. This could be incoming broadcast traffic from other hosts. No way to tell.

Comment: So I can't ask here what/how Speccy is measuring? Incoming broadcast traffic is sucking up 800 Kbps on the network? Really.

Answer (score 1):

I'm at home with a stable internet and I'm seeing the same picture.
[image]
So, I guess it's perfectly normal.
If you want to see if your internet is not stable I suggest you queuing up ping in cmd. `ping -n 1000 8.8.8.8` and see the delta between maximum and minimum.